# Incorporating Images into XSL+XML

Tags: html, xml, image, xslt

I'm working on a project for one of my classes where I need to display film information generated from an XML document. While looking up other questions that may relate to mine, I didn't really understand the answers and the solutions didn't change anything. What I want to happen is for me to make reference to the images once and have it instantiate for each instance of my "movie" element the way it works for the titles and other attributes and elements. Here's an example "movie" element from my XML code:

```
<movie>
        <title title="L'Ile aux chiens" year="2018" language="English, Japanese" genre="Animation, Adventure, Comedy" imdb="tt5104604"/>
        <poster src="isle of dogs.png"/>
        <director>Wes Anderson</director>
        <writers names="Wes Anderson, Roman Coppola, Jason Schwartzman, Kunichi Nomura"/>
        <actors names="Bryan Cranston, Koyu Rankin, Edward Norton, Bob Balaban"/>
        <plot>Set in Japan, Isle of Dogs follows a boy's odyssey in search of his lost dog.</plot>
    </movie>
```

Here's the code I have so far for my XSL:

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="film_css.css"/>
                <title>Discography of Wes Anderson</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Discography of Wes Anderson</h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="//movie">
                    <h3><xsl:value-of select="title/@title"/></h3>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//poster"/>
                        <img src="{src}"/>
                    <div id="infos">
                        <p>Year: <xsl:value-of select="title/@year"/></p>
                        <p>Writers: <xsl:value-of select="writers/@names"/></p>
                        <p>Actors: <xsl:value-of select="actors/@names"/></p>
                        <p>Plot: <xsl:value-of select="plot"/></p>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm still kind of new to all this coding stuff (I just started in September at the beginning of my master degree, I'm from a linguistics background), so it'd be much appreciated if any responses were kind of dumb-downed for me! (Not much, but you know how it is as a beginner.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src` is not a child element of `movie` you need to give proper path upto `@src` like:

```
<img src="{poster/@src}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="//poster"/>
<img src="{src}"/>
```

use

```
<img src="{poster/@src}"/>
```

You just have to apply the same logic as what you have already done for Year, Writers, Actors, and Plot.

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly